Getting some error with my test DB2 stored procedure
I am new to stored procedure and trying to create a simple stored procedure to read from table. I am using IBM DB2 SQL.
--#SET MAXERRORS 0                                  
--#SET TERMINATOR ~                                 
SET CURRENT SQLID = 'SIWRO1'~                       
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DWR000A.SELECT_PSID_RIZ(
  IN P_CONN INT                                     
 ,IN P_PLNN INT                                     
)                                                   
LANGUAGE SQL                                        
RESULT SETS 1                                       
READS SQL DATA                                      
BEGIN                                               
  DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR                             
  SELECT PSID,                                      
         JOBINFO                                    
  FROM DWR000A.TEST                               
  WHERE CONN = P_CONN                               
  AND PLNN = P_PLNN;                                
  OPEN C1;                                          
END         
 ~                 
--#SET TERMINATOR ;
COMMIT;                                                 

I'm getting this error when executing it:
SQLERROR ON   CREATE    COMMAND, PREPARE   FUNCTION                      
RESULT OF SQL STATEMENT:                                                
DSNT408I SQLCODE = -4743, ERROR:  ATTEMPT TO USE A FUNCTION WHEN THE APPLICATION COMPATIBILITY SETTING IS SET FOR A PREVIOUS LEVEL                                                 
DSNT418I SQLSTATE   = 56038 SQLSTATE RETURN CODE                        
DSNT415I SQLERRP    = DSNHSM5R SQL PROCEDURE DETECTING ERROR            
DSNT416I SQLERRD    = 50  0  0  -1  1  2721 SQL DIAGNOSTIC INFORMATION  
DSNT416I SQLERRD    = X'00000032'  X'00000000'  X'00000000'  X'FFFFFFFF'
         INFORMATION                                                    

I am not able to figure what I am doing wrong or how to fix it. I appreciate some expert advice.
Thanks
Update
11/28/2024  I managed to bypass the error by doing 1 function which is to create. Thanks

This error is specific to your Db2-for-Z/OS subsystem configuration.
The description of the error code is here
In short it means you are trying to use some functionality that is not yet enabled for your target Db2-subsystem.
Speak with your DBA for Db2-for-Z/OS to learn about the compatibity level (  APPLCOMPAT system parameter ) that is configured for your target subsystem,  and which functionality is enabled for that subsystem.
With that information, refer to the Db2 Knowledge Centre for Db2 for Z/OS for the exact version that the compatibility level specifies.
The DBA might also enable a higher compatibility level if it is a testing subsystem, which may allow your procedure to compile and run.
